# on a doubtful point?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I understand the meaning of this sentence:

> A bad teacher will aim at imposing his opinion, and turning out a set of pupils all of whom will give the same definite answer **on a doubtful point**.

But I don't know the exact meanig of 'point' here. Does it mean *time*, *situation*, *idea* or ...? Since the preposition 'on' is used, maybe *time* is the correct answer.

Comment: "Doubtful" in this text, implies the meaning of a suspected point (a point which an argument is made on) that  he is asking for an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "point" here means "subject" or "topic" Which also requires the same preposition "on". It doesn't refer to time.The meaning from oxforddictionaries.com.

> A single item or detail in an extended discussion, list, or text.
>   ‘the main points of the Edinburgh agreement’

Comment: Thanks. **answer to something** is the structure we usually use. I can't remember seeing **answer on something**. Of course, the given sentence was written about 100 years ago.